# How can I store and load my Sessions as a User on Parse?

Tags: java, android, session, parse-platform

I am currently developing an Android app for existing IOS app, so using Session object to store some data on Parse is crucial for me.

As for creating and uploading sessions to Parse I have no problems.

```
public static void syncUser() {
    ParseUser.getCurrentUser().fetchInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.d("", "SYNC ERROR");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (object != null) {
                syncSessions();
            }
        }
    });
}

private static void syncSessions() {
    ParseQuery<ParseSession> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(ParseSession.class);
    query.fromLocalDatastore();
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseSession>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseSession> objects, ParseException e) {
            for (ParseSession session : objects) {
                fetchSession(session, null);
            }
        }
    });
}

public static void fetchSession(final ParseSession session, final OnResultCallback cb) {
    session.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                if (cb != null)
                    cb.onResult(false);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } else {
                if (cb != null)
                    cb.onResult(true);
                ParseRelation<ParseSession> relation = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getRelation("sessions");
                relation.add(session);
                syncUser();
            }
        }
    });
}

public static void addNewSession(Date date, String link, int successValue) {
    final ParseSession session = new ParseSession();
    session.put("date", date);
    session.put("link", link);
    session.put("successValue", successValue);
    session.pinInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e != null)
                e.printStackTrace();
            else {
                fetchSession(session, new ParseManager.OnResultCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(boolean success) {
                        if (success) {
                            try {
                                session.unpin();
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

public interface OnResultCallback {
    void onResult(boolean success);
}
```

For creating new Session with my parameters and uploading it I use addNewSession() method, and it displays in Parse dashboard correctly, they have columns for my fields (date, link, successValue) and are stored as the default Session object.

But when I try to load them from Parse to my client, it doesn't work. I load them with this method:

```
public static void getSessions(final OnResultCallback cb) {
    ParseRelation<ParseSession> relation = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getRelation("sessions");
    ParseQuery<ParseSession> query = relation.getQuery();
    query.setLimit(1000);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseSession>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseSession> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (cb != null)
                    cb.onResult(false);
            } else {
                cb.onResult(true);
            }
            //if (objects != null)
            //USE SESSIONS
        }
    });
}
```

I catch an exception:

```
W/System.err: com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: wrong type of relation.  Expecting: , but received: _Session
W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRequest.newPermanentException(ParseRequest.java:270)
```

Quite similar code on IOS works fine with "sessions" relation. What mistakes have I done?

UPD. I have noticed that I get this exception only when I have allready send some custom created Session to Parse with addNewSession() and then trying to get them using getSessions(). Maybe creating and sending the Session is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the sollution. After I add my newly created Session to User relations with

```
ParseRelation<ParseSession> relation = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getRelation("sessions");
relation.add(session);
```

I tried to save them with fetchInBackground, which was a mistake. I changed syncUser() to ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground() and everything worked.